# How to use for loop in list in python 3?

Tags: list, for-loop, python-3.7

I have a question about writing for loops in python 3.

Basically, I don't understand how to write for loop if I have a list that contains two elements, like this one:

```
list1 = [("Berlin", 22), ("Zagreb", 30), ("New York", 25), ("Chicago", 20), ("Paris", 29)]
```

This is basically a list that contains cities and their temperatures in Celsius degrees, and I would like to create a new list that contains cities but now their temperature in Fahrenheit. The formula is:

F° = (9/5)*C° + 32

I don't understand how am I suppose to loop through this list that contains two elements in every member.

Comment: Do you tried to loop over the list to get each item? Do you know how to access each individual element of a tuple?

Comment: I tried to loop over the list, but I get an error. I know how to access each individual element of a tuple.

Comment: Just a heads up for future questions, it would have been much better to have posted the code that you tried with the error, and asked about that instead. It's good you got an answer here, but it's much more likely when you ask a more narrow question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [("Berlin", 22), ("Zagreb", 30), ("New York", 25), ("Chicago", 20), ("Paris", 29)]

list2 = [(city, 9/5 * temp + 32) for city, temp in list1]

print(list2)
# [('Berlin', 71.599999999999994), ('Zagreb', 86.0), ('New York', 77.0), ('Chicago', 68.0), ('Paris', 84.200000000000003)]
```

Here, you iterate through list of tuples getting city names to `city` and temperature in Celsius to `temp` and convert Celsius to Farenheit.

Without list comprehension:

```
list2 = []

for city, temp in list1:
    list2.append((city, 9/5 * temp + 32))

print(list2)
# [('Berlin', 71.599999999999994), ('Zagreb', 86.0), ('New York', 77.0), ('Chicago', 68.0), ('Paris', 84.200000000000003)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you also show me how to do this without using list comprehensions?

Comment: @CroSimpson2.0, please find it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is to access elements in a 2D list. According to your `list1`, city is in the 0th position and temperature is in 1st position in a row. Within a simple for loop, you can access those as follows. Remember to keep the indentation, to specify the body of the for loop.

```
for element in list1:
    city = element[0]
    temp_c = element[1]
```

Then you can directly use `temp_c` to compute temperature in Fahrenheit (`temp_f`), within the loop.

```
temp_f = (9 / 5) * temp_c + 32
```

Next task is to append calculated `temp_f` values to a new list (`list2`) along with city name.

```
list2.append((city, temp_f))
```

But before that you should define the `list2`. (somewhere near you define `list1`)

```
list2 =[]
```

So it's done. You can check it works using a print statement.

```
for element in list2:
    print(element)
```

This code can be implemented much shorter.
I expand it to reduce the complexity. Hope you got it.